# how to print result of _.zip.apply()

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, apply

I am trying underscore.js for the first time and want to transpose my row array into column. As, I need to join it with 2D array

I checked discussion here and found can be done by `_.zip.apply()`. But, when I am trying it, it is not showing any reuslt

```
  Final = my 2D array
  dtr = ['s', 's', 'n'];
```

I need to join dtr with final such that every element in dtr is a column header in           final array doing this:

```
  _.zip.apply(dtr, Final)
```

but it is not showing any result

expected outcome:[image]

my 2d array:-[image]

and the dtr array need to go at top of the 2d array.. hope it is clear.

Comment: People will be better able to help you if you provide valid code and a properly formatted question.

Comment: Also, what is the expected output?

Comment: @thefourtheye  please check expected outcome

Comment: @user3050590 It is still not clear. Can you please show the 2D array as well?

Comment: @acjay   dtr is 1D array as showed in question and final is a 2d array that I have read from a csv file.. Rest, please check expected outcome which is similar to the screenshot.

Comment: @thefourtheye please check the 2d array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want your dtr array to be the first array in the 2d array. One could do this:

```
var a = ['s','s','n'];
var b = [[50, 50, 50], 
         [50 , 5, 5],
         ['hello', 'beta', 'gama']];

var result = [a].concat(b);
```

Result:

```
[['s','s','n'],
 [50, 50, 50], 
 [50 , 5, 5],
 ['hello', 'beta', 'gama']];
```

Edit

```
var a = ['s','s','n'];
var b = [[50, 50, 'hello'], 
         [50,  5, 'beta'], 
         [50,  5, 'gama']];

var result = _.map(_.zip(a, b), _.flatten) 
// if native map support _.zip(a, b).map(_.flatten)
```

Result:

```
[['s', 50, 50, 'hello'], 
 ['s', 50,  5, 'beta'], 
 ['n', 50,  5, 'gama']];
```

Comment: I did that and getting an error like anonymous function[underscore-min.js] . Also,my 2d array is in form like b in case 1 but, I do not want to transpose this array, I want to transpose array a.

Comment: I forgot to wrap the a array into [a] before concat call. Though it would still be in wrong format. Lets see...

Comment: thanks,, I wrap array into square braces and it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

My answer contains two cases, which are dependent on how array b is organised.

Case one:

```
var a = ['s','s','n'];
var b = [[50, 50, 'hello'], 
         [50,  5, 'beta'], 
         [50,  5, 'gama']];

_.zip(a, b).map(_.flatten) // -> [Array[4], Array[4], Array[4]]
```

Case Two

```
var a = ['s','s','n'];
var c = [[50, 50, 50], 
         [50 , 5, 5],
         ['hello', 'beta', 'gama']];
var b = _.zip.apply(null, c); // content equals to case one variable b

_.zip(a, b).map(_.flatten) // -> [Array[4], Array[4], Array[4]]
```

Result:

```
[['s', 50, 50, 'hello'],
 ['s', 50,  5, 'beta'],
 ['n', 50,  5, 'gama']]
```